# Golang json Unmarshal "unexpected end of JSON input"

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I am working on some code to parse the JSON data from an HTTP response. The code I have looks something like this:

```
type ResultStruct struct {
    result []map[string]string
}

var jsonData ResultStruct
err = json.Unmarshal(respBytes, &jsonData)
```

The json in the `respBytes` variable looks like this:

```
{
 "result": [
  {
   "id": "ID 1"
  },
  {
   "id": "ID 2"
  }
 ]
}
```

However, `err` is not nil. When I print it out it says `unexpected end of JSON input`. What is causing this? The JSON seems to valid. Does this error have something to do with my custom struct?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you read in `respBytes`?

Comment: Also, note that lowercase indicates private visibility.  You want the field name in your `ResultStruct` to be capitalized: otherwise the `json` decoder isn't allowed to touch the field.  See: http://play.golang.org/p/bATT5uMPRT for an example that appears to work.  So we need more information to see what your error is: the question as stated doesn't have enough to tell.

Comment: @dyoo `respBytes` is just an array of bytes (I take the response, do some processing and extract the body). I also capitalized the result field in the `ResultStruct`. Your Go playground example takes the JSON I receive and handles it correctly, so there must be something else wrong with my code... Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `unexpected end of JSON input` is the result of [a syntax error](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/9af454c588ee0bef7fc6ae588e2b2e866edcb915/src/encoding/json/scanner.go#L160) in the JSON input (likely a missing `"`, `}`, or `]`). The error does not depend on the type of the value that you are decoding to.

I ran the code with the example JSON input [on the playground](http://play.golang.org/p/bhtjDbwKJi). It runs without error.

The code does not decode anything because the `result` field is not exported. If you export the result field:

```
type ResultStruct struct {
   Result []map[string]string
}
```

then the input is decoded as shown in this [playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/KLYR9MTKnm).

I suspect that you are not reading the entire response body in your application. I suggest decoding the JSON input using:

```
err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&jsonData)
```

The decoder reads directly from the response body.

Comment: I suspect that besides of what @3of3 said, you try to parse your JSON without last '}' character.

Comment: This makes sense, however I printed out the JSON and ran it through an online validator as well as through @dyoo's Go playground example and it succeeded. I must conclude that this error is due to an issue with another portion of my code. Thanks!

Comment: JSON validator here https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 6):

You can also get this error if you're using json.RawMessage in an unexported field. For example, the following code produces the same error:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type MyJson struct {
    Foo bool `json:"foo"`
    bar json.RawMessage `json:"bar"`
}

type Bar struct {
    X int `json:"x"`
}

var respBytes = []byte(`
{
  "foo": true,
  "bar": { "x": 10 }
}`)

func main() {
    var myJson MyJson
    err := json.Unmarshal(respBytes, &myJson)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    myBar := new(Bar)
    err = json.Unmarshal(myJson.bar, myBar)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

If you export "MyJson.bar" field (e.g. -> "MyJson.Bar", then the code works.

Comment: you just saved my day. I wouldn't have thought that it would be this issue. Thank you!

Comment: it gives **unexpected end of JSON input** error

Answer (score 1):

it is not the case here; but if you are getting this error loading json from a file it Will occur if the byte slice for the buffer is not initialized the the byte size of the file. [when you're new like me that happens! ]  Since this is the first search result I got it still took some digging to figure out.  In this use case the error is a bit misleading.

```
type GenesisResultStruct []GenesisField

fileinfo, _ := genesis.Stat()
bs := make([]byte, fileinfo.Size())
//bs := []byte {} // wrong!!
_, error := genesis.Read(bs)

if error != nil {
    fmt.Println("genesis read error: ", error)
    os.Exit(1)
}

var jsonData GenesisResultStruct
eGen = json.Unmarshal(bs, &jsonData)

if eGen != nil {
    fmt.Println("genesis unmarshal error: ", eGen)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue today.

You can also get this error if the `respBytes` is `nil` or there are no brackets `[]` if you are unmarshalling it to a slice.
In that case, you need to explicitly set `respBytes`.

As you are unmarshalling it to a slice, brackets `[]` are expected in the byte-slice

```
if src == nil {
    src = []byte("[]")
}
```