# Go: unexpected end of JSON input and json.Unmarshal returns nil values

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I'm testing out how to unmarshal a json response from an API I'm using.

The json looks something like the following;

```
body := []byte(`[
    {"name":"Name1", "value":100.00},
    {"name":"Name2", "value":200.00}
]`)
```

I've searched around for various ways to do this, but fail to get this to work. The unmarshal returns zero values. I also get an error "unexpected end of JSON input" (I've removed the error handling in the example).

Full code example - https://play.golang.org/p/VMdWuAm6HS

Reference:

1. https://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage
2. [Golang json Unmarshal "unexpected end of JSON input"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994327/golang-json-unmarshal-unexpected-end-of-json-input)
3. [How to unmarshal json into interface{} in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254102/how-to-unmarshal-json-into-interface-in-golang)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input JSON can be modeled with a simple `[]Obj` where `Obj` is your type:

```
type Obj struct {
    Name  string  `json:"name"`
    Value float32 `json:"value"`
}
```

Nothing else is required, really:

```
body := []byte(`[
    {"name":"Name1", "value":100.00},
    {"name":"Name2", "value":200.00}]`)

var res []Obj
err := json.Unmarshal(body, &res)
fmt.Printf("%#v\n%v\n", res, err)
```

Output contains the data from the input JSON (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/K7tV07W5_i)):

```
[]main.Obj{main.Obj{Name:"Name1", Value:100}, main.Obj{Name:"Name2", Value:200}}
<nil>
```

**Back to your code:**

Where you're going wrong is that you use this model:

```
type Obj struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Value float32 `json:"value"`
}

type Result struct {
    Data json.RawMessage
}

var res []Result
```

But this `res` variable would model the following JSON:

```
[
    {"Data":{"name":"Name1", "value":100.00}},
    {"Data":{"name":"Name2", "value":200.00}}
]
```

I think you can see the difference: the elements of the array here are JSON Objects with a `"Data"` field, which then are modeled with your `Obj`. This input JSON is then properly parsed with your original parsing code, you can try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Urn4QsdyBj):

```
[{{"name":"Name1", "value":100.00}} {{"name":"Name2", "value":200.00}}] 
&main.Obj{Name:"Name1", Value:100} 
&main.Obj{Name:"Name2", Value:200}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!